# telethon: filtering events by the type of the chats they are coming from

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

i wanna filter the `events.newMessage` to fire only when messages are coming from private chats.
but i don't want to put all chat ids in chats list argument of the event

do you have any ideas ?

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'hello' in event.raw_text:
        await client.delete_messages(await event.get_chat(), event.id)
```

in the example above think i a want to delete all messages coming from private chats ( everyone of them )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NewMessage` events implement the [ChatGetter](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/custom.html?#module-telethon.tl.custom.chatgetter) class so you can use the following :

`event.is_private` → User

`event.is_group` → Chat and Channel (megagroup flag set)

`event.is_channel` → Channel

Also for a more of a complete answer

```
any private = is_private
any group = is_group
any channel = is_channel
only small groups = is_group and not is_channel
only mega groups = is_group and is_channel
only broadcast channels = not is_group and is_channel
```